# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}H_n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers, mobius-function

For integers $n\geq 1$ let $$H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}$$ the $nth$ harmonic number, and $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function. See, if you need it, this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) to know the definition of Möbius function.

After I've read a problem due to Furdui from [1], I would like to ask about the convergence of a similar series:

> **Question.** What is a good way to deduce if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}H_n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}$$ does converge? **Thanks in advance.**

### References:

[1] Furdui, *PROBLEMA 94* from La Gaceta de la Real Sociedad Matemática Española Vol. 11, No. 4 (2008).

Comment: It's hard to immediately prove because of the conditional nature of convergence, but it seems highly likely. $\sum\frac{\mu(n)\ln n}{n}$ converges (to -1) and it's hard to imagine that the inner terms would 'conspire' to push the series towards divergence.

Comment: I've no a good idea of how to study the convergence of this series. I know that it is required to study it using absolute convergence, and that we will need some asympotics. But I don't know a good strategy to solve the problem.

Comment: Many thanks @StevenStadnicki I was writting previous comment for all users. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}$ is convergent and $\sum_{k\geq n+1}\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$ in absolute value, so the given series is convergent.

Comment: Many thanks feel free to add you comment as hints for an answer @JackD'Aurizio And my apologizes to you and all users because seems a bad question.

Comment: You already asked 10 times the same question. Do you study the answers ?

Comment: Many thanks @user1952009 now I know the argument. I will not forget it. After I've read Jack's answer I wrote this $$ \left|   \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}H_n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n} \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}\right| ,$$ as companion of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a very crude estimation
$$\left|\sum_{k\geq n+1}\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}\right|\leq \sum_{k\geq n+1}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{n} $$
since $\left|\mu(k)\right|\leq 1$. Since 
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=2\,\zeta(3) $$ is a convergent series, the given series is convergent too.